# Call Javascript Function before Razor calls my HTML Helper

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've been working on a HTML helper which will hide or show menu items depending on what type of user you are.

For this reason, In one of my controllers I am setting a session variables with values such as "ADMIN"

```
context.Session["perfil"] = "ADMIN"
```

The problem I am facing is that the Helper function is being called before the Javascript function which calls the controller that sets the session variables

This is how I call my HtmlHelper  (through Razor)

```
 @using XSiteManagerWeb.Helpers
 @Html.Raw(Html.MiMenu("../Home/Configuracion", "Configuración"))
```

From my _Layout.cshtml

But before doing that I'm calling the function

```
 <script type="text/javascript">ObtenerDatosSesion();</script>
```

Which calls a Controler method through Ajax

```
...
$.ajax({
        url: "../Home/ObtenerDatosSesion",
....
```

**Question:** Why is the HtmlHelper being called before `ObtenerDatosSesion();`  even though I've put it before on the _Layout.cshtml ?

I've also tried calling in on window load doing this:

```
<body class="Fondoblue" onload="ObtenerDatosSesion();">
```

among other methods.

I noticed the Helper is being called before everytime after many debuggings.  What I can't figure out is why that happens.

I wonder if it has anything to do with the Web.config line one has to put to use html helpers

```
<add namespace="XSiteManagerWeb.Helpers"/>
```

**So to make it clear, I just want to make my `"ObtenerDatosSesion();` method gets called before my html helper!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The razor helpers are executed server side, therefore they will be executed **before** any JS is rendered/executed on the page.

I would recommend moving whatever logic is in your `../Home/ObtenerDatosSesion` endpoint to the same endpoint as `../Home/Configuracion`.  If it's going to be called more than once, you can put it in its own method.

Comment: *they will **always** be executed before...*

Comment: That's all I needed to know.